# Google App Scripts - Getting a constant "Yesterday"

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm trying to set a const "Yesterday" but the script is not recognised as a function (I'm using Google App Scripts).
I've tried different syntax including:

```
const yesterday = today.setDate(-1);
```

and

```
const yesterday = new Date(today.setDate(-1));
```

But neither worked.
I'm pretty sure it should be a minor change but I cannot figure out how to solve this.
A little help would be highly appreciated, thanks !

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('My Report');

  function insertColumn() {
  const range = sheet.getRange('H1:H69').getValues();
  const newrange = sheet.getRange('I1:I69');
  const rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+7", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  const yesterday = new Date(today.setDate(-1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `today` is not a `Date` object, because you've called `Utilities.formatDate` on it. This is why you are getting an error when trying to use `today.setDate()`. So you need to use another variable to allow you to compute `yesterday`. For example:

```js
const tmp = new Date(); 
const yesterday = new Date(tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate()-1))
```

Also note that [`setDate(-1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) sets the date to the penultimate day in the previous month (e.g. March 30 when you are in April), you need to get the current date (using [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)) and subtract 1 from that to get yesterday's date.

Comment: const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Keyword Report'); 

  function insertColumn() {
  const range = sheet.getRange('H1:H69').getValues();
  const newrange = sheet.getRange('I1:I69');
  const rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  const today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");

  sheet.insertColumnAfter(8);
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  newrange.setValues(range);
  sheet.getRange('H2').setValue(today).setNumberFormat("MMMM DD yyyy");
  }

Comment: Sorry I should had put my entire piece of code first it would have helped. My bad.
I tried to replace my const "today" with your new const "yesterday" (using the function).
But then my new column is renamed "function (){ today =...."

Comment: You would need to use `setValue(yesterday())` to actually call the function.

Comment: To minimise changes to your code, I think you really want just `const tmp = new Date(); const yesterday = new Date(tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate()-1))`

Comment: I'm getting an error message "TypeError: today.getDate is not a function"
See message below:
https://imgur.com/U53crMu

Sorry I'm a beginner programmer maybe I got something very basic wrong.

Comment: If you're using the code from my previous comment note I added the variable `tmp` to use in the code. You can't use `today` because it's not a `Date` object because you called `Utilities.formatDate`

Comment: My bad, I didn't not get this on the first read. Thanks a lot it works and my code stays clear and simple, awesome !

Comment: Good to hear. I'll update the answer so it's clear to anyone else who sees this.

Answer (score 0):

```
getYesterday() {
  let date = new Date();
  let yesterday_milliseconds = date.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  let yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setTime(yesterday_milliseconds);
  let strYear = yesterday.getFullYear();
  let strDay = yesterday.getDate();
  let strMonth = yesterday.getMonth() + 1;
  if (strMonth < 10) {
    strMonth = "0" + strMonth;
  }
  if (strDay < 10) {
    strDay = "0" + strDay;
  }
  return strYear + "-" + strMonth + "-" + strDay;
},
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so subtracting 8.64e7 milliseconds won't necessarily give yesterday, e.g. if it's run after 23:00 (or 23:30 in some places) on the day that DST ends. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function yesterday() {
  let dt = new Date();
  Logger.log(new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1)));
}
```

From MDN setDate() returns: The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date... not a date object

Comment: The issue with doing it this way is that there is a very slight possibility that the month might change between calls to `new Date()`, so if - for example - you transition from April 30 to May 1, the function will return May 29 instead of April 29.